# DirectX проблема с буфером Z

Tags: c++, графика, 3d, directx

Изучаю DirectX. Подключаю z буфер, но он не работает! Но зато появляются кривые некрасивые рябящие в глазах мерцания.

Вот мои параметры

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS params;
ZeroMemory(&params,sizeof(params));
params.Windowed = true;
params.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
params.BackBufferFormat = display.Format;
params.BackBufferCount = 3;
params.BackBufferWidth = display.Width;
params.BackBufferHeight = display.Height;
params.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
params.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24X8;
params.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = display.RefreshRate;
params.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_DISCARD_DEPTHSTENCIL;
params.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
```

Рендер состояния

```
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, TRUE);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC, D3DCMP_LESSEQUAL);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE,D3DCULL_CCW);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING,TRUE);
device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_AMBIENT, 0xaaaaaa);
```

И очистка буфера

```
device->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET| D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,255), 1.0f, 0 );
```

Где косяк подскажите плиз.

Comment: Не могу найти. Посмотрите http://progs.biz/directx/direct3d/vc/lessons/012.aspx и
http://progs.biz/directx/direct3d/vc/lessons/013.aspx

Comment: благодарю за старание,но погуглить и сам могу.мне был нужен совет человека работающего в этой области.

Answer (score 1):

Так вы чистите Z-буффер какими-то странными значениями (цвета 0;0;255), вот и получаете фигню, потому что глубина каждой точки сравнивается не с какой-то глубиной, а со значением цвета, что является бредом. Z-буффер нужен для теста глубины и в начальном состоянии он должен содержать такие значения, чтобы любая точка проходила тест глубины (Например, 0;0;0)

Comment: Я разобрался с проблемой. Проблема заключалась в матрице проекции. она неадекватно реагирует на установку положения передней отсекающей плоскости меньше нуля.

 device->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET| D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,255), 1.0f, 0 );

а эта строка очищает буфер и делает фон синим. и ничего здесь плохого нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Достаточно одного внеэкранного буфера.
params.BackBufferCount = 3; //1

// включаешь стенсил-буфер но в рендере не используешь
params.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;//FALSE

//ишь ты, смотри чтобы видеокарта поддерживала этот режим
//для этого проверяй CheckDeviceFormat
params.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24X8;

//для оконного режима задай такие настройки
params.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
params.PresentationInterval       = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
```